# Add the WHERE clause to this SQL query

Tags: sql

might be something stupid but I need to add the WHERE (i.e. WHERE id=1) clause to this SQL query but i keep gettin error.
What is the proper way to implement?
Thanks in advance.

The SQL query:

```
("SELECT i.*,c.fullname  
from `invoice_list2` i 
inner join impianti_list c 
on i.impianti_id = c.id 
order by id desc 
LIMIT $start1, $limit1");
```

Comment: what error do you get? what is your attempt?

Comment: The where clause must be added before the order by part in this case.

Comment: Now i'm searching for an invoice with status=1, and i get this error:
Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\invoice\data.php:127 Stack trace: #0, I added the WHERE clause before the order by part

Comment: Maybe you should have a look on SQL documentations/tutorials, this woul help a lot. You should use table aliases and put them before column names, this will prevent such issues.

Comment: Yes, @JonasMetzler, it helped, it was definetly it. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I needed to specify from which table I would select the elements using aliases:

```
SELECT 
i.*,c.fullname  
from 
`invoice_list2` i 
inner join 
impianti_list c 
on 
i.impianti_id = c.id 
WHERE 
i.status=1 
order by 
id desc 
LIMIT 
$start1, $limit1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query is correct , You can use your result as subquery to filter your records.

> select * from (SELECT i.*,c.fullname
> from `invoice_list2` i
> inner join impianti_list c
> on i.impianti_id = c.id
> order by id desc
> LIMIT $start1, $limit1) as tmp where tmp.id = 1